# How to locate the value inside a div using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

How to locate value inside a div using xpath \ css_selector

I have this html:

```
<div class="catalog-products view-tile" data-catalog-products="" data-slider-available="" data-primary-as-icon=""><div data-id="product" class="catalog-product ui-button-widget" data-product="5a7b4c6d-0bc3-11ec-a2b0-00155dfc8232" data-code="4862447" data-preview-slider-inited="1"><div class="catalog-product__image"><a class="catalog-product__image-link" href="/product/5a7b4c6d0bc3c823/videokarta-msi-geforce-210-n210-1gd3lp/" data-toggle-slider=""><picture><source type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 768px)" etc
```

So I need to get data-code value **4862447**

1. Tried to access via xpath:

   ```
   /html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]
   ```

   Got highlighted in Chrome console that part:

   ```
   <div data-id="product" class="catalog-product ui-button-widget" data-product="5a7b4c6d-0bc3-11ec-a2b0-00155dfc8232" data-code="4862447" data-preview-slider-inited="1">
   ```

   Don't know how to get data-code value.
2. Tried css_selector:

   ```
   div[data-id='product']
   ```

   Got same line:

   ```
   <div data-id="product" class="catalog-product ui-button-widget" data-product="5a7b4c6d-0bc3-11ec-a2b0-00155dfc8232" data-code="4862447" data-preview-slider-inited="1">
   ```

   And no idea again.

Comment: I can access main line via xpath\class_name (catalog-product ui-button-widget)\css_selector but have no idea hot to get smth inside div open tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the value of the *`data-code`* attribute you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.catalog-products.view-tile > div.catalog-product.ui-button-widget[data-id='product']"))).get_attribute("data-code"))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='catalog-products view-tile']/div[@data-id='product' and @class='catalog-product ui-button-widget'][.//a[@class='catalog-product__image-link' and @href and @data-toggle-slider]]"))).get_attribute("data-code"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks but that element is visible, smth wrong with get_attribute - it works with "href" attribute but not with "data-code". When i search with "driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-code]")" - i get all elements, they are visible. But i get elements 'lower' that div not 'inside' it

Comment: Visible to you and me with our naked eyes doesn't confirms it's visible to Selenium and vice versa. Checkout the updated XPATH.